# How to load SIVP toolbox through scilab console?

Tags: scilab

I use GUI to select and load SIVP toolbox in scilab.
How do I do it through scilab console ?

Answer (score 1):

If you've installed the toolbox through the ATOMS package manager, you can load it using the following command:

```
atomsLoad SIVP
```